# Simple PHP proxy with persistent URL

Tags: php, curl, proxy, request, echo

I have the simple PHP script:

```
<?php
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
if (preg_match('/\b(https?|ftp):\/\/*/', $url) !== 1) die;
echo (file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

I am trying to echo the page:

```
http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=162984431&page=10
```

but the echo shows:

```
http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=162984431
```

example:

http://www.kylesbox.com/forumbuddy/fetch/fetch.php?url=http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=162984431&page=10

I am not a PHP expert but I think this has something to do with persistent URLs? How would I go about fixng this so the echo displays everything after the & symbol as well? I do have cURL installed on my server if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the "&" sign is part of query string element. So it will avoid to get value from first "&". We can two more lines on your script to get the work done.

```
<?php
$query=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];  //get the full query string in url
$query_arr=explode("url=",$query);  //split the string by first get key

$url = $query_arr[1];  //take second parameter as url to be loaded
if (preg_match('/\b(https?|ftp):\/\/*/', $url) !== 1) die;
echo (file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

The she script available at following url as working script.

http://sugunan.net/demo/fetch.php?url=http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=162984431&page=10